# Problems with the gulp watch

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, gulp

I am preparing a project, and decided to use the gulp collector. I wrote commands, but gulp watch does not work. It does not produce any errors in the terminal at startup, because of this it is difficult to understand what the problem is. Maybe someone came across a similar one.

I enclose the code in gulpfile.js

```
    'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    prefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    rigger = require('gulp-rigger'),
    cssmin = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
    rimraf = require('rimraf'),
    browserSync = require("browser-sync"),
    reload = browserSync.reload;

var path = {
    build: {
        html: 'build/',
        js: 'build/js/',
        css: 'build/css/',
        img: 'build/img/',
        fonts: 'build/fonts/'
    },
    src: {
        html: 'src/*.html',
        js: 'src/js/**/*.js',
        style: 'src/style/**/*.scss',
        img: 'src/img/**/*.*',
        fonts: 'src/fonts/**/*.*'
    },
    watch: {
        html: 'src/**/*.html',
        js: 'src/js/**/*.js',
        style: 'src/style/**/*.scss',
        img: 'src/img/**/*.*',
        fonts: 'src/fonts/**/*.*'
    },
    clean: './build'
};

var config = {
    server: {
        baseDir: "./build"
    },
    tunnel: false, /* Создание временного тунеля заблокированно */
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9000,
    logPrefix: "Eugene Kobeliaksky"
};

gulp.task('webserver', function (done) {
    browserSync(config);
    done();
});

gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    rimraf(path.clean, cb);
});

gulp.task('html:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.html) 
        .pipe(rigger())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('js:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.js) 
        .pipe(rigger()) 
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) 
        .pipe(uglify()) 
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write()) 
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));//edit live reload
});

gulp.task('style:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.style) 
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            sourceMap: true,
            errLogToConsole: true
        }))
        .pipe(prefixer())
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('image:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.img) 
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
            use: [pngquant()],
            interlaced: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.img))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('fonts:build', function() {
    gulp.src(path.src.fonts)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.fonts))
});

gulp.task('build', [
    'html:build',
    'js:build',
    'style:build',
    'fonts:build',
    'image:build'
]);


gulp.task('watch', function(){
    watch([path.watch.html], function(event, cb, done) {
        gulp.start('html:build');
        done();
    });
    watch([path.watch.style], function(event, cb, done) {
        gulp.start('style:build');
        done();
    });
    watch([path.watch.js], function(event, cb, done) {
        gulp.start('js:build');
        done();
    });
    watch([path.watch.img], function(event, cb, done) {
        gulp.start('image:build');
        done();
    });
    watch([path.watch.fonts], function(event, cb, done) {
        gulp.start('fonts:build');
        done();
    });
});


gulp.task('default', ['build', 'webserver', 'watch']);
```

Comment: Why the `path.src.html` is different from the `path.watch.html`? I not see any reason the have different values for `src` and `watch`. you should not separate it at all

Comment: First, all HTML files are assembled, after which the changes are viewed. It turns out the assembly, it works, but does not change in real time, you have to restart the build script all the time

Comment: it's work when you run the build script, because it's use the `src.html` path, which is correct. it's not updated in real time because the watch script used the `watch.html` path, which is wrong. please try to change the `watch.html` path to be the same as the `src.html`

Comment: Please specify where to make changes. I changed in the below function, but that didn't help           gulp.task('watch', function(){});

Comment: change the value of the object `path` at `path.watch.html` from `'src/**/*.html'` to `'src/*.html'`

Comment: It looks like you are using gulp v3, not v4.  Is that correct?  What do you get with `gulp -v` in the terminal?

Comment: Hello! yes i am using gulp 3.9.1

Comment: Thank you for responding, I rewrote the code a bit, and everything works